# Hiding part of a webpage from search engines?

Tags: php, search, seo

I'd like to make part of a webpage ignored by search engines.
Is this possible?
I want search engines to notice only the title and content, not comments, menus, and etc.

Example

```
<p>content 1</p>
<p class='crawlers-cannot-see-this'>content 2</p>
```

Comment: Part of a page, or part of a site (i.e. a number of pages)? Please show an example

Comment: Search engines are smart enough to distinguish between menus and content. Comments, on the other hand, are content. You shouldn't try to hide them from search engines. (You should try to stop people filling your page up with irrelevant comments, but that's a problem of its own)

Comment: Care to explain the use case here? There are tricks you can do as people have said involving javascript and iframes, but it's hard to tell what's really the best approach without knowing what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dynamic content through Javascript or simply use an iframe.

There is nothing that will otherwise tell a spider not to index a block of code or content.

For a server side distinction use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` but like I've stated it's not necessarily the most reliable.

Ex.

```
<?php
$spiderSearch = array(
        "GoogleBot"=>"Googlebot",
        "MsnBot"=>"msnbot",
        "Yahoo! Slurp"=>"Slurp",
        "YahooSeeker"=>"YahooSeeker"
        //more search terms from
        //http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/
);

$isSpider = false;
foreach($spiderSearch as $name=>$val){
    if(preg_match('/'.$val.'/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
        $isSpider = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!$isSpider){
    //SHOW COMMENTS
}
?>
```

Comment: robots.txt will, if the spider sticks to the rules.

Comment: Also note that The Google can get more than a bit touchy when she suspects she is being fed content different from other visitors. She calls it [cloaking](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66355) and if she catches you, then be afraid, be very afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Filter user-agent or use robot.txt

Comment: robot.txt is for ignoring pages, not what the OP was asking for. You could filter user-agent via PHP but it's not a very secure method.

Comment: @J.Romero: I believe that is exactly what the OP wants. That content is ignored.

Comment: @Markus. J. Romero is right. I don't want the whole page ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe for hiding content, iframe content can be something like :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <p> This is my content </p>
  </body>  

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just out of curiosity, why would you want to hid comments? comment posts usually related to what you've write and it will increase the keyword naturally in that page hence increase your keywords optimization. my apology if my comment is out of topic :)

in my knowledge you can use iframe to avoid any indexing by crawlers